# Firefox window shows up blank after Windows 10 Creator Update

Tags: windows-10, firefox

I am having a fairly new issue that I am struggling with right now.

It doesn't matter what window I have open in Firefox. After a bit it will show up completely blank. You can still see hyperlink when you are hovering over certain area where there is something to click. So the only problem is short of doing a task manager -> kill Firefox. Then restart Firefox to fix it.

Then after a bit it will come back after a while. I never had problem with Firefox under Windows 10 until the [Creator Update](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history#Version_1703_(Creators_Update)_2) that happened fairly recent.

This is what I see if the problem show up. You can clearly see all tabs are finish loaded, but they all show up blank just like the current one.

[image]

Comment: Backup your Firefox user profile, delete your current Firefox user profile, see if the behavior still happens

Comment: go to firefox options and disable HW acceleration and the new seperate GPU process for firefox.

Comment: Look like wiping out my firefox user profile didn't prevent this. It took a while to cause it to happen again. So I am going to try disable HW acceleration.